# call spoofing online server

Tags: phone, spoofing, gsm

My friend has an app, in which he dials my number, and on my mobile, I see my own number calling me. He basically spoofs my number. He claims that there are online call services via which we can do that.

How is that possible?

Comment: https://www.spoofcard.com/

Comment: @JulianKnight nope they just call via a differetnt num, simple act as a middle man